# Nuxt Auth Module c5 doesn't refresh token automatically when token expires

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

#### Version

module: 5.0.0-1624817847.21691f1
nuxt: 2.15.8

#### Nuxt configuration

- Universal

#### Nuxt configuration

```js
// Auth: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/ (v5)
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/account/login/',
    logout: '/account/login/',
    callback: '/account/login/',
    home: '/account/beams/'
  },
  strategies: {
    local: {
      scheme: 'refresh',
      token: {
        property: 'access_token',
        maxAge: 120, // seconds, 2 minutes
        global: true
      },
      refreshToken: {
        property: 'refresh_token',
        data: 'refresh_token',
        maxAge: 1209600 // seconds, 2 weeks
      },
      user: {
        property: 'user',
        autoFetch: true
      },
      endpoints: {
        login: { url: '/api/account/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
        refresh: { url: '/api/account/refresh', method: 'post', },
        logout: { url: '/api/account/logout', method: 'post' },
        user: { url: '/api/account', method: 'get' }
      },
      autoLogout: false
    }
  }
},
```

### Additional information

### Checklist

- [x]  I have tested with the latest Nuxt version and the issue still occurs
- [x]  I have tested with the latest module version and the issue still occurs
- [x]  I have searched the issue tracker and this issue hasn't been reported yet

#### Steps to reproduce

#### What is expected?

When a user's token expires and `refresh` scheme is implemented, a user shouldn't be logged out and redirected back to the login screen, the refresh token should be used to obtain a new token and the transition should be seamless allowing any authenticated route to continue to work.

#### What is actually happening?

In my Nuxt project with the Auth module I've implemented the `refresh` scheme, however, when my token expires I don't see any request in my network being made to the `refresh` route after my token expires and I navigate to a protected page via the `auth` middleware.

I expect I'm missing some simple configuration?

My current token has an expiry of 1 minute for testing, and my refresh token has an expiry of 14 days for testing.

However, when adding:

- `scheme: 'refresh'`
- `refresh: { url: '/api/account/refresh', method: 'post', }`

the functionality appears to not be fetching my user and automatically logging me in.

My `/api/account/refresh` endpoint in my API returns the following:

```
{
  refresh_token: 'my refresh token',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  expired_in: 5000
}
```

My `/api/account/login` endpoint in my API returns the following:

```
{
  access_token: 'my token',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  expired_in: 1000
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return refresh token from /api/account/login. And then set in conf property name of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with very similar comfiguration. This is my result from API (I added refresh token to the result):

```
{
    "access_token": "XXX",
    "refresh_token": "XXX", 
    "expired_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

If I inspect cookies, I can see acces token, but refresh token does not set:

[image: Cookie list after login]

I try to manually set refresh token after login, but with same result:

```
const result = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
  data: this.login,
})

this.$auth.setUserToken(result.data.accessToken, result.data.refreshToken)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).